# How to change language manually using kotlin compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi::class)
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val windowSize = calculateWindowSizeClass(this).heightSizeClass
            App(windowSize != WindowHeightSizeClass.Compact)
        }
    }

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val getSP = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val actualLanguage = getSP.getString("language", this.getString(R.string.english))
        val languageId = when (actualLanguage ?: this.getString(R.string.english)) {
            this.getString(R.string.hungarian) -> "hu"
            else -> "en"
        }
        (application as Application).actualLanguage = actualLanguage
        val resources = this.resources
        val configuration = resources.configuration.
        val locale = Locale(languageId)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        configuration.setLocale(locale)
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
    }

override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        val uiState = ViewModelProvider(this)[ViewModel::class.java].uiState.value
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val edit = sharedPreferences.edit()
        edit.putString("language", uiState.actualLanguage)
        edit.apply()
    }
}
```

```
class ViewModel : ViewModel() {
    fun onSettingsApplyClicked(context: Context) {
        if (uiState.value.actualLanguage != uiState.value.selectedLanguage) {
            changeLanguage(uiState.value.selectedLanguage)
            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun changeLanguage(language: String) { _uiState.update { it.copy(actualLanguage = language) }    
}
```

This code works fine, but "updateConfiguration()" says deprecated.

Based on the searches, I found that it could be solved somehow with the help of "context.createConfigurationContext()" and "CompositionLocalProvider()".
I would like an example code if possible.

Comment: I can not understand what changing language using Kotlin compose means. please explain what you meant

Comment: It's what `updateConfiguration` does. Except that is deprecated now. The question is what to use instead.